# Advantage of directExecutor

Tags: java, guava

As far as I understand Guava's [MoreExecutors.directExecutor()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#directExecutor()) creates an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html?is-external=true) which will executes the runnable before the execute method call could return.

What are the usecases that need direct executor ? Can't the caller directly call runnable.run() directly instead of the extra level of indirection by creating an executor and submitting the runnable to this executor ? May be I am missing the real purpose of it's existence. I wanted to understand in what case is this useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few places which require both `Runnable` and `Executor`.

One of then is for example `ListenableFuture` and its [`addListener`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html#addListener-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) method. The only way how to execute listener immediately within the same thread is to provide direct executor.

Answer (score 3):

`MoreExecutors.directExecutor()` is useful when you call an API that requires you to specify an executor to execute the task (e.g. `Futures.transform()`, `listenableFuture.addListener()`, etc).

Note that when you use `directExecutor()` with these APIs, the runnable may be run on one of these two threads:

- The thread that completes the previous future
- The thread that calls `transform()`/`addListener()`

This uncertainty could cause unexpected issues. So be careful when you use `directExecutor()`.